# How to make NSSortDescriptor not in alphabetical order?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I have a simple shopping list. So far the list is being added alphabetically. When I do ascending false, it goes from Z-A and ascending true is from A-Z.

I just want the items to be added based on when they were added. No ordering, no nothing. It just adds to the back of the list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Shopping")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "item", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
```

Comment: remove this line `fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]`or pass empty array like `this fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []`

Comment: That may not actually work. If these objects are fetched via a relationship they will be a Set and not ordered.

Comment: @ReinierMelian After doing this, the list is not alphabetical which is great but the ordering is weird, the items are not added in the back but are added randomly in the centre and other places

Comment: @user3449976 I miss understood your question, but thankfully someone has answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you must add something like a date-added field to your `Shopping` object. Then you sort on that date-added value.

This is simply because database (including CoreData) tables don't have an intrinsic ordering. (Often the underlying database engine does generate id's that may seem to increment. But you should never rely on these internal values.)

Comment: Did you fill in a date for all existing items, that were there before you added a date?

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I inserted the date into the date attribute, did the following line: let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false). Also adding this to my other file:  @NSManaged var date: NSDate

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting based on the name, I assume that's what `item` is in this line of code

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "item", ascending: false)
```

If you want to sort by something else, add a property called `createdDate` (or something) which you can initialise in the ManagedObject's `awakeFromInsert` method, and then you can use that as the sort key:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createDate", ascending: false)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I didn't need to do the awakeFromInsert and worked well without it. I've never used the property before so I'll have a look into it.

Comment: awakeFromInsert is run only once in the lifetime of an NSManagedObject - the first time it is inserted into an NSManagedObjectContext. It's a very useful place to to initialise an object particularly for creation dates.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am quite a beginner so this is very useful!